# getting error in sending mail in backend as Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND smtp.getMaxListeners.com

Tags: reactjs, node.js, backend, mern, nodemailer

I am developing  portfolio in mern stack and I want send email through use of nodemailer but I am getting this error.

**Getting error in controller for sending mail**

```
PS D:\Porfolio> node server.js
Server Running On PORT 8080
node:internal/errors:465
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND smtp.getMaxListeners.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:79:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'EDNS',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'smtp.getMaxListeners.com',
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

**PortfolioController.js**

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    
    host:"smtp.getMaxListeners.com",
    port:587,
    secure:true,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL,
      pass: process.env.WORD,
      
    },
});
const sendEmailController =(req,res)=>{
    try {
        const {email,subject,msg}=req.body
        if(!subject || !email || !msg){
            return res.status(500).send({
                success:false,
                message:'Please provide All Fields'
            })
        }
        var mailOptions={
            to:email,
            from:process.env.EMAIL,
            subject:subject,
            text:msg,
        }
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
        return res.status(200).send({
            success:true,
            message:"Your Message Send Successfully",
        })
       
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).send({
            success:false,
            message:'Send Email API Error',
            error
        });
    }
}
module.exports={sendEmailController};
```

**portfolioRoute**

```
const express =require('express');
const { sendEmailController } = require('../controller/portfolioController');
//router object
const router=express.Router();
//routes
router.post('/sendEmail',sendEmailController)
//export
module.exports=router;
```

**Contact.js**

```
import React ,{useState}from 'react'
import './Contact.css'
import {BsLinkedin,BsGithub} from 'react-icons/bs'
import Pulse from 'react-reveal/Pulse';
import {  toast } from 'react-toastify';
import axios from 'axios'
const Contact = () => {
  const [subject, setsubject]=useState("");
  const [email, setemail]=useState("");
  const [msg, setmsg]=useState("");
  //handle submit button
  const handleSubmit=async (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      if(!subject || !email || !msg){
        toast.error('Please Provide all Fields');
      }
      const res=await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/portfolio/sendEmail',{email,subject,msg});
      if(res.data.success){
        toast.success(res.data.message)
        setemail("");
        setsubject("");
        setmsg("");
      }else{
        toast.error(res.data.message);
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Pulse>
      <div className=' contact' id='contact'>
      <h2 className='col-12 mt-3 mb-1 text-center text-uppercase'>Contact me</h2><hr/>
        <div className='card card0 border-0'>
          <div className='row'>
            <div className='col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-sm-12'>
              <div className='card1'>
                <div className='row border-line'>
                  <img src='https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/hot-line-contact-us-call-center-search-interface_53876-124009.jpg?w=2000' alt='ocontact' className='image'/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='col-md-6 col-lg-6'>
              <div className='card2 d-flex card border-0 px-4 py-4'>
                <div className='row'>
                  <div className='row'>
                    <h6 className='d-flex justify-content-center'>
                    
                      <a href='#'>
                        <BsLinkedin  color='blue'size={30} className='ms-2' />
                      </a>
                      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                      <a href='#'>
                      <BsGithub  color='black'size={30} className='ms-2'/>
                      </a>
                    </h6>
                  </div>
                
                <div className='row px-3 mb-4'>
                  <div className='line'/>
                  <small className='or text-center'>OR</small>
                  <div className='line'/>
                </div>
                <div className='row px-3'>
                  <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='Enter Your Email' className='mb-3' value={email} onChange={(e)=>setemail(e.target.value)}/>
                </div>
                <div className='row px-3'>
                  <input type='text' name='subject' placeholder='Enter Your Subject' className='mb-3' value={subject} onChange={(e)=>setsubject(e.target.value)}/>
                </div>
                <div className='row px-3'>
                  <textarea type='text' name='msg' placeholder='Enter Your Message' className='mb-3' value={msg} onChange={(e)=>setmsg(e.target.value)}/>
                </div>
                <div className='row px-3'>
                  <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={handleSubmit}>SEND MESSAGE</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </Pulse>
    </>
  )
}
export default Contact
```

For above I am running react application and server seperately.if send mail from the frontend it will getting send successfully send but getting error in server side code please help me to solve my problem thanks you though!